# Using MS Excel to simulate a formula using a variable?

Tags: excel

I'm very confused on how to use Microsoft Excel to simulate a "problem", but I've been assured that it's possible.

I have the equation

```
v(t) = (mg/c)(1-e^((-c/m)(t)))
```

And I know the values of m, g, k, and c.

```
m = 170
g = 32 ft/s^2
k = 2.5 lb/ft
c = 1.2 lb/ft/s
```

So my formula changes into

```
v(t) = (170*32/1.2)(1-e^((-1.2/170)(t)))
v(t) = (453.33)(1-e^((-.00705)(t)))
```

The problem is about a bungee jumper, and this is one function that I should use to find velocity, and another that is used for x (distance), but if I can learn how to properly implement this one, I should be able to easily figure out the other one.

I need to somehow implement this in Excel, as a spreadsheet simulation. I have no idea how to implement this in Excel, and I don't know the formulas to do it. I know I could just go through the formula manually and just substitute variables in for t (i.e., .5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, ...), but I know there's supposed to be some way for Excel to do it for me. Additionally, I'm not sure how to simplify the powers and the "e" in my formula, and I actually don't know if I *need* it if I can just sub in variables like I think I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: The other state equation, x(t), is below

```
x(t) = (mg/c)(t) + ((m^2 * g) / c^2))e^((-c/m)(t) - (m^2 * g / c^2))
```

Comment: What is your aim here?  You can certainly enter the formula and values of t and get Excel to calculate the v(t) values, and then plot a graph or whatever.  But what do you require?

Comment: I'm trying to simulate the jumper's trajectory, using the state variables v(t) and x(t). The guy's standing on a bridge 240ft high, and the cord is 90 ft long, so the only distance this guy can go is  90 feet total. The goal is to use the spreadsheet simulation to tell if the jumper will be safe in the end. I'll update my question with the x(t) state equation.

Comment: Well anyway, I'd plot the values of x and v in a couple of columns with various values of t in another column, and see what the value of v is when x is about 90.

Comment: "the cord is 90 ft long, so the only distance this guy can go is 90 feet total" - that's one stiff bungee cord: I would not sign up for that!

Comment: I'm guessing cheese-wire

Comment: Ok, but what I need help with is how to input it as a formula in excel to get it to calculate my values. Can anyone help me on how to do that?

Comment: It's just a regular Excel worksheet formula - with a little translation from your example:  `e^x` becomes `EXP(x)` and you need to add `*` between the `)(`

Comment: Ok, how would I set it up to run a bunch of instances though with T being different values from say, .5 to 10 with a step of .5?

Answer (score 0):

This formula as mentioned in the OP:

> v(t) = (453.33)(1-e^((-.00705)(t)))

needs a little adaptation, as suggested by @Tim Williams, to be suitable for Excel:

```
=453.33*(1-EXP(-.00705*t)
```

Excel does not multiply letters by numbers but will attempt to interpret `t` above as a named range (which may contain one or more numbers) before objecting. So `t` may be the name given to a range starting `.5` and stepping `.5` up to and including `10` (may easily be created with Fill , Series…).

If the above formula is then placed in the same row as `0.5` and copied down to suit the results should be as required.

It may however be worth noting that naming a range as a single letter is not best practice and for accuracy, convenience and versatility the constants (eg re gravity) and the variables (eg mass) would be better fed as parameters to the formula.